# Run Time Error 13 - compare to true

Tags: vba

Have simply this line of code as shown below:

```
If Cells(L, i).Value = True
```

Then i receive following error message:

```
Run Time Error 13. Type mismatch.
```

Could someone tell me why i get this error message?

This column L has either empty cells or some formulas like:

```
=IF(OR($O11="";$CJ11=0;AH$6<$CJ11);"";IF($CJ11=AH$6;TRUE;IF($O11="S";TRUE;IF(OR(AND(RIGHT($O11;1)="M";$O11<>"M");RIGHT($O11;1)="S");IF(MOD(AH$6-$CJ11;LEFT($O11;LEN($O11)-1)*IF(RIGHT($O11;1)="M";4;1))=0;TRUE;FALSE);IF($O11="M";IF(MOD(AH$6-$CJ11;4)=0;TRUE;FALSE);IF(RIGHT($O11;1)<>"A";MOD(AH$6-$CJ11;$O11)=0;FALSE))))))
```

Comment: What do you what to compare with the cell's value ? Do you want to compare with the string `"True"` ? Here,  your `True` is a boolean type

Comment: @MincongHuang interestingly, the expression evaluates to `True` even if the cell content is the string `true` (`='true`). I don't know what happens with different language versions though.

Comment: Ah, you're right. @arcadeprecinct

Comment: Not sure if that could cause the error but the first argument of `Cells` is the Row, not the Column.

Comment: L is number, L=9 i=24 and both are integers and as i see this cell is empty

Comment: check my main post - i paste the formula in that cell

Answer (score 2):

Two possible reasons (that I know of) why a `Type mismatch` error might occur here.

1. `L` or `i` are not natural numbers. Fix: make sure the arguments are natural numbers. (for example if `L` is a range, use `L.Row`)
2. The cell contains an error. Fix (if you can't remove the error):

   ```
   If Not IsError(Cells(L, i).Value) Then
       If Cells(L, i).Value = True Then 'you could also omit the "= True"
           'do stuff
       End If
   End If
   ```

   Since VBA has no lazy evaluation, it is necessary to split the tests up.

The reason you can't find the error might be that you are looking at the wrong cell. In your question you wrote "column L" but the cell you reference is in *row L* and *column i*.

Comment: L=9 i=24 and both are integers and as i see this cell is empty

Comment: @JimmyJimm That's odd then, I couldn't reproduce your problem. Can you find a simpler example of a cell content that causes the error? Like a formula that other people can use. The formula you have in the question is hard to read and other people can't evaluate it.

Comment: @JimmyJimm I was able to create a `Type mismatch`, maybe you referenced the wrong cell. See my edit.

Comment: check my main post - i paste the formula in that cell

Comment: @JimmyJimm Yes but that formula is still pretty complicated. Why not `=IF(TRUE;"";"Somethingelse")`? That should have the same result. It still doesn't give me an error though (Your formula doesn't either). Did you check the column/row thing that I mentioned?